# Saber quais div contem uma class especifica em jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando saber a quantidade de divs que contem uma class especifica, pensei em buscar todos os css que tenho nas divs, assim ir eliminando até achar as divs com "has-error", só que não estou conseguindo achar quem exatamente tem a class "has-error"

Como fazer?

```
$(document).on('click', "#btnSalvar", function () {

    var erros = 0;
    $("div").find('*').each(function () {
        var classe = $(this).attr("class");
        if (classe !== undefined) {
            if ($("" + classe + ":contains(has-error)")) {

            }

        }
   });
});
```

O que fiz até agora.

Edit:

Como que marca solucionado para duas pessoas ao mesmo tempo? hhaha
Valeu a todos

Comment: Não sei se eu entendi muito bem, mas não seria mais simples utilizar o [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)?  Ficaria algo parecido com isso: `$('div.has-error')...` Você também poderia remover a 'div' e deixar somente a classe.

Comment: Acredito que sim, mas não estou sabendo implementar, como ficaria no meu código?

Comment: var numItems = $('.item').length;

Comment: valeu cara, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer de uma forma simples com jQuery:

```
$("div.has-error").length
```

No caso acima irá encontrar apenas `div`s com a classe. Para contar qualquer, use:

```
$(".has-error").length
```

No seu código, ficaria:

```
$(document).on('click', "#btnSalvar", function () {
    var erros = $("div.has-error").length;
});
```

**Com JavaScript puro:**

```
var erros = document.body.querySelectorAll("div.has-error").length;
```

Comment: kkkk, iguais né

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo a minha tá canônica rs

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a propriedade jquery  [**.length**](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

```js
var numItems = $('.has-error').length;

console.log (numItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="has-error"></div>
    <div class="has-error"></div>
    <div class="has-error"></div>
    <div class="has-error"></div>
    <div class="has-error"></div>
    <div class="no-has-error"></div>
    <div class="no-has-error"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 pelo exemplo funssional. :D

Comment: @dvd grafia errada é fumssional com M, o n só precede ç

Comment: Aquele lance de `$("#div1", "#div2")` significa: buscar #div1 dentro de #div2... agora `$("#div1, #div2")` significa selecionar as duas ids.

Comment: Beleza, vou buscar uma aplicação de `#div1 dentro de #div2` que nunca vi